# How to limit an inner query by outer query attribute

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a requirement to sort a table by multiple criteria, select the first and associate with another table.  The DB is Postgres.

Let's say we have `players` and `teams` where player has played from several teams.  This is not the real composition of the model but should suffice for our example.

The requirement is to get the most recent record of the `team` the `player` played for, ordered by `teams.end_date` if it's present, otherwise by `teams.start_date`.

The algorithm would seem to be group by `players.id`, and order by the criteria mentioned above.  However all of my attempts to limit the results to 1 gives me the first `team` record that is ordered by that criteria.

Here's what I think is the closest I got:

```
SELECT 
  latest_teams.* 
FROM players
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      player_id,
      team_name,
      start_date,
      end_date
    FROM teams
    ORDER BY .... --this part is fine
    limit 1
  ) AS latest_teams
  ON players.id = teams.player_id
```

How can I get the scope of the inner query to be that of the player id?

Comment: You could try breaking the query into multiple parts.  You could use a temp table to store the initial set of data, then select the next set of data by joining.  The temp table could be replaced by a common table expression as well.  I find that complex joins (based on results of subqueries, ones that contain OR's, etc) tend to get overly complex and difficult to debug later on.  This is my opinion formed after years of rewriting other peoples code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you `SELECT` only from the `teams` table and there is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint that `REFERENCES players`, you don't need the join to `players` at all.

Now, there are various ways to write this type of queries, there is even a tag at SO and DBA.SE, [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group). We need the greatest 1 in this case. The most simple code is to use the `DISTINCT ON` construct (which is a Postgres, non-standard addition to SQL).
If you need columns from `players`, you can simply join and add the columns in the select list.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.player_id)
  t.player_id,
  t.team_name,
  t.start_date,
  t.end_date
FROM teams AS t
  -- JOIN players AS p            
  --   ON p.id = t.player_id
ORDER BY 
    t.player_id,  -- this needs to match the DISTINCT ON ()
    ....      -- pick what order you want, so the 1st is chosen for each player
 ;            -- no LIMIT
```

Another way that works in most other DBMS is to use window functions. The criteria for which row to be chosen goes inside the `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT 
    g.player_id,
    g.team_name,
    g.start_date,
    g.end_date
FROM
  ( SELECT 
      t.player_id,
      t.team_name,
      t.start_date,
      t.end_date,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.player_id 
                         ORDER BY ...) AS rn
    FROM teams AS t
      -- JOIN players AS p            
      --   ON p.id = t.player_id
  ) AS g
WHERE
    g.rn = 1 ;
```

If you are not in some ancient version of Postgres, there is also the `LATERAL` syntax, that is often the most efficient. Especially when there is a "driving" table with the distinct values we want to base the grouping (the `players` here) and if these values are relatively small in number and have many possible options (i.e. in this case, the biggest the `teams` table is, in comparison to the `players`, the better for this query).
Also notice how this query resembles very much your initial idea. It does, literally, exactly what you want: allow the `players` columns to be referenced inside the `lt` subquery:

```
SELECT
    lt.player_id,
    lt.team_name,
    lt.start_date,
    lt.end_date
FROM players AS p
  JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT t.*
      FROM teams AS t 
      WHERE p.id = t.player_id
      ORDER BY ....     -- pick the order
      LIMIT 1 
   ) AS lt ON TRUE ;
```

Comment: I used the lateral join and it worked, but it is causing the performance to suffer.  It's a huge query, and it went from about .5-1 sec to execute to now being like 5+ seconds.  Is that what you'd expect?  It's important to note that the order by is 4 columns, plus a derived value from a case statement.

Comment: Indexes would help but which index to add depends on the ordering condition. For example, if you want to find the team with the latest `start_date`, an index on `(player_id, start_date)` would be fine.

Comment: Which query to choose will depend on the distribution of your data. How many rows do the 2 tables have? Of course you can try and test performance of all the different ways to write this (there are more!)